# Create database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create a new database. Before this I am using [`master`]. When importing files into new database, I got an error.

Could not allocate a new page for database '`new`' because of insufficient disk space in file group '`PRIMARY`'

I already clear my disk space. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should find your solution [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46643/could-not-allocate-a-new-page-for-database-because-of-insufficient-disk-space)
which describes the problem related to the error message : `Could not allocate a new page for database because of insufficient disk space` and the matching solution 
.
Hope this help.

Comment: I already tried to increase size of filegroup 'Primary' but failed. It says that 'CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database'.